# What should I do for separating a string?

Tags: java

For example I have a string "1234" that I want to break into two strings "12", "34".  Is there any method for doing that? How?

Comment: Johanna, I don't mean to be rude (really!), but looking at your list of questions over the past month or so, I'm not entirely sure you spend *any* time looking at Javadocs or even basic Java references.  I assure you that the best way to learn Java (or any language) **by far** is to read the documentation and learn by doing.

Comment: I totally agree. It also amazes me that people continually spend time helping. Not once out of the last 14 posting has Johanna accepted an answer. All the poster does is take ideas try them out and if the don't work, post another question asking for someone to debug the code. Of course the problem is not Johanna who is smart enough to let everyone else do the work. The problem is the people in the forum who keep spoon feeding answers.

Comment: It's a good training for real-life co-worker support.

Comment: Unfortunately this is often how incompetent coworkers, consultants, and vendors "code". I try to encourage people learning Java or another language to ask questions and do their own research because it's important to learn how to learn. Unfortunately it's sometimes difficult to make a distinction between the ones trying to learn and the ones just using you as a code monkey.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that at this point, we can put Johanna into the category of people using the SO community to do her learning for her.

Comment: delfuego - just ignore Johanna's questions and let us help her in the way she asks for help.

Answer (score 10):

You might use the [substring](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) function:

```
"1234".substring(0, 2);
"1234".substring(2, 4);
```

It takes a begin index and an end index, returning the substring between the two.

Comment: While it's really nice to jump on questions like this in order to boost your rep here, you really shouldn't provide answers to people who haven't even tried to find them out for themselves first. One of these days, you and I are maybe going to have to maintain or support the "code" they've produced. See @delfuego and @camickr's comments to the original question.

Comment: @ken I've learned some things the same way, by asking and being answered to the point. It terribly irritates me when I ask something and I'm being answered with a general "look for it yourself" kind of reply - I generally ask about two types of things: the ones that I'm really interested in but I couldn't find an answer even after extensive searching and the ones that I wouldn't give a f*ck about even if you would wire me to a f*ck giving machine - but I have to do the thing anyway, so I seek community help. This is why I understand such questions and try to be helpful to the point.

Comment: Luvieere, I find it hard to imagine that someone of your ilk and rep here would neglect to even *open the damn Javadocs* before posting your question to SO -- that's the distinction we're trying to make.  Look at Johanna's posting history, and convince me/us that she's actually making **any** effort other than clicking a bookmark to the SO "Post a new question" page, typing a semi-comprehensible string of jibberish into the box, and clicking submit...

Comment: I won't try to convince you of anything **but** of the fact that I would do **the very same thing** if it were about a math problem. I **hate** math, I truly do, I used to cheat at math papers in high school so I could get a D - so I would make **the same** amount of infinitesimal effort if it were for me to solve a math problem at work, and I would blatantly ask the damn thing on a forum or something. I personally know people that have the same adversity for Java that I have for math - therefore I do not blame them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generically solve this problem (let's say you want to split a string in half), then extend what luvieere suggested...

```
String aString = "1234";
int length = aString.length();
System.out.println(aString.substring(0,length / 2));
System.out.println(aString.substring(length / 2,aString.size());
```

Something like that.  (Of course, that doesn't handle an odd-length string, but I'll leave that up to you.)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [substring()](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-string-substring-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is actually "what separator should I use to demarcate individual values in a string", the answer is it doesn't matter as long as it's not going to be present in your normal input data. For example, you could use "^|*" as your separator in most situations because it's unlikely to be coincidentally present in normal input data.

If your question is "how do I split a string delimited by a known separator", you can use `StringTokenizer`, `String.split()` with a regex, or `String.indexOf()` combined with `String.substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the javadocs, substring sounds useful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to do something with Strings, then have a look at the <strike>static</strike> methods declared on the String class.

In fact String.substring() can't 'break' a String in two parts, but it returns a part of the original String and you can assemble your break requirement with two substring operations, like luvieere explained in another answer.

Usually you use String.split() to break a String in parts, but with substring there's an easier solution for your problem.

Comment: "...look at the static methods..." substring() and split() aren't static.

Answer (score 0):

use the string split method

for example

```
  String s = "1234";
  s.Split(".{2}.{2}" = {"12", 23"}  // a String array
```

Comment: - compilation errors: method split must start with lowercase,...  

- logic error: results in empty string, the regex `.{2}.{2}` is the delimiter, not what is being searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also you String Tokenizer.  If there is a character that you want to split the string with.

For example "Stack Overflow", could be split into two tokens "Stack" and "Overflow" using the white-space (" ").

[JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

[Examples](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/96string_examples/example_stringToArray.html)